# How to remove noisy logs with Android Device Monitor

Tags: android-studio

I have the following three errors flooding up logcast incessantly:

```
E/eglCodecCommon: **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,73)
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd
```

My goal is to remove these noisy logs from the console logs in Android Studio.

I go to tools > Android > Android Device Monitor. 
Under Logcat tab, I select + icon. I enter Filter name "Noisy egl". I enter Log tab `eglCodecCommon` because that is what Logcat says the tag name is. I save it.

But as soon as my app launches Facebook Login on the Emulator, those errors reappear. How can I filter them out?

Answer (score 12):

In the top-right corner of your log tab, select "Edit filter configuration" and use this. Make sure regex check box is checked. Good luck.

```
^(?!(eglCodecCommon|anyOtherTags|YouWantToExclude))
```

Answer (score 6):

Under 'logcat' tab at bottom of android studio, make sure you choose correct options for emulator, package and log level.
[image]
In botton right corner, choose edit filter configuration and add following configs:

Logtag:

`^(?!(eglCodecCommon|GnssLocationProvider|system_process|audio_hw_generic|tagToExclude))`

Package name:

`^(?!(com.google.android.gms.persistent|android.os.Debug|packageToExclude))`

Or you can just add `'com.yourPackageName'` under package name. Make sure that 'regex' option is selected for both.

Answer (score 6):

Answer from `Andrej Jurkin` does not work (anymore?) in Android Studio 3.6.

Here is the updated Regex:

`^((?!eglCodecCommon|anyOtherTags|YouWantToExclude).)*$`

Enter this in the filter and make sure that "Regex" is checked.

Comment: This worked for me in Android studio 4.1.1 in January 2021

Answer (score 0):

Is there an update to this solution for Android Studio 2022? There does not seem to be a filter edit option any more and putting the text specified here into the filter at the top of the window does not work.